# How to increase the size of the image and save the picture

Tags: python, graphviz, pydot, pydotplus

I am trying to visualize a set of RDF turtles and I am using the following the code:

```
!pip install pydotplus
!pip install graphviz

import io
import pydotplus
from IPython.display import display, Image
from rdflib.tools.rdf2dot import rdf2dot

def visualize(g):
    stream = io.StringIO()
    rdf2dot(g, stream, opts = {display})
    dg = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(stream.getvalue())
    png = dg.create_png()
    display(Image(png))

visualize(g)
```

Here, the g inside visualize(g) is my rdfgraph.

An image is indeed created but it's too small and I donot know how to save it. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use opencv to resize images.

```
import cv2

image=cv2.imread("Your image")
image=cv2.resize(image,("your expected x co-ordinate value","your expected y co-ordinate value"))
cv2.imwrite("location where you want to save",image)
```

Example

```
image=cv2.imread("myimage.jpeg")
image=cv2.resize(image,(700,700))
cv2.imwrite('/home/desktop/',image)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import io
import pydotplus
from IPython.display import display, Image
from rdflib.tools.rdf2dot import rdf2dot

def visualize(g):
    stream = io.StringIO()
    rdf2dot(g, stream, opts = {display})
    pydot_graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(stream.getvalue())
    pydot_graph.write_png('original_tree.png')
    pydot_graph.set_size('"5,5!"')
    pydot_graph.write_png('resized_tree.png')
```

> All the attributes defined in the Graphviz dot language should be
> supported.
>
> Attributes can be set through the dynamically generated methods:

```
set_[attribute name], i.e. set_size, set_fontname
```

Click on the pictures to get a sense for size since it doesn't seem to show up properly in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i have already tried it and have no effect on the output :(

Comment: Yes I have, but no effect